# Failed to load resource error

Tags: lightning-web-components

I pushed my new LWC to the scratch org, but I encountered to following error while attempting to load the page containing the LWC.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

Is this because I'm using the scratch org? Below is the basic structure of my LWC.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import D3 from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myModule';

export default class myComponent extends LightningElement {
    d3Initialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.d3Initialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.d3Initialized = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, D3 + '/mainDirectory/config.js'),
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.initializeD3();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading D3',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                    }),
                );
            });
    }

    initializeD3() {

    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be your static resource issue, are you sure that it's correctly uploaded and available?

Comment: I was able to successfully pull into my project from the scratch org, and the resource resides in the 'staticresources' directory. Should I change the 'Cache Control' to public to make it available?

Comment: That wouldn't have an impact. I cannot seem to find any other reason as why this won't work.